# Как можно перебрать и найти сумму элемента этого объекта(js)?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, объекты

```
let obj = {
    key1: {
        a: 1, b: 2, c: {
            d: 3,
            e: 4,
        }, f: 5,
    },
    key2: {
        g: 6, h: 7,
    },
}
```

Comment: что значит "перебрать"?

Comment: я имею ввиду перебрать циклом его ключи, чтобы найти сумму чисел

Comment: пишите рекурсивную функцию, которая на вход получает объект и в ней перебираете поля. Если поле объект - то снова вызываете функцию, а поле передаете как параметр.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так

Так как ключи нам не интересны только значения. Нужно посмотреть не является ли значение объектом и просуммировать его, а если да то рекурсия.

```js
let obj = {
    key1: {
        a: 1, b: 2, c: {
            d: 3,
            e: 4,
        }, f: 5,
    },
    key2: {
        g: 6, h: 7,
    },
}

function Sum(obj) {
  return Object.values(obj).reduce((acc, item) => { acc+= (item instanceof Object)? Sum(item): item; return acc;}, 0);
}

console.log(Sum(obj));
```